# ERROR: Path to downloaded Udacity course/Nanodegree doesn't exist (udacimak)

Tags: git, docker, path

I want to download my courses I'm enrolled in at Udacity to study them when I'm offline.
I tried "udacimak" to do this through (Git Bash) and I actually went through the steps described here  https://github.com/udacimak/udacimak and downloaded the course content as jason files in a directory on my computer.

The problem is at the rendering step; when I run `udacimak render C:\Users\IamOmarDarwesh`, it gives me this error:

`2019-03-11T16:50:37.600Z [error]: ERROR: Path to downloaded Udacity course/Nanodegree doesn't exist.
STACK: Error: Path to downloaded Udacity course/Nanodegree doesn't exist.
    at renderCourse (C:\Users\IamOmarDarwesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\udacimak\lib\commands\render\functions\renderCourse.js:43:11)`

So, how can I solve this? Am I doing something wrong?
Can anybody help me with clearer steps?

I suspect that the problem that I couldn't run the code lines under the section of

> Use Udacimak via Docker container

such as `docker pull udacimak/udacimak` and `docker container run -it -v "$(pwd)/:/downloads" udacimak/udacimak --help` It gives an error `bash: docker: command not found`

I tried by all means to figure this out but I couldn't.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding quotes to your folder location:

```
udacimak render "C:\Users\IamOmarDarwesh"
```